# Is there a standard way of documenting vbscript

Tags: vbscript, documentation, doxygen

Is there a standard way of documenting vbscript?
[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) doesn't currently appear to support vbscript, but are there any similar tools available?

Comment: @oraclecertifiedprofessional: Hmm, not sure how I missed that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the other question linked to by oracle certified professional, [VBSdoc](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/vbsdoc.shtml) will create vbscript documentation using a doxygen-like syntax.

[VBDOX](http://vbdox.sourceforge.net/) is an alternative.